# JclShell.ShellLinkResolve gets wrong data

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-shell

`JclShell.TShellLink.Target` gives back the wrong path:

```
uses
  JclShell;
...
var
  ThisShellLinkRecord: JclShell.TShellLink;
  ThisTargetExePath: string;
begin
  JclShell.ShellLinkResolve('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Xara\Xara Designer Pro X9\Xara Designer Pro X9.lnk', ThisShellLinkRecord);
  ThisTargetExePath := ThisShellLinkRecord.Target;
```

`ThisTargetExePath` from the above code results as:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Xara\Xara Designer Pro X9\DesignerPro.exe`
Please note the `(x86)` in the resulting target path which indicates the 32-bit program files path.

HOWEVER, this is the wrong path and does not exist! When I manually open the Properties dialog of the Xara Designer Pro start menu link from the Windows Start Menu, the target path is:
`C:\Program Files\Xara\Xara Designer Pro X9\DesignerPro.exe`
Please note that this is the 64-bit program files path and DOES exist!

So why does ShellLinkResolve give back the wrong data here?

**EDIT**: I've opened the link in Notepad++: I've found only the ABSOLUTE 64-bit program files path in it (no environment variable), see here: [goo.gl/jWUDb9](http://goo.gl/jWUDb9)

**EDIT2**:

You are right, there are different results if compiled as a 32-bit program or as a 64-bit program:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ThisShellLinkRecord: JclShell.TShellLink;
begin
  JclShell.ShellLinkResolve(Edit1.Text, ThisShellLinkRecord);

  {$IFDEF WIN32}
    Form1.Caption := 'This is a 32-bit program';
    Label1.Caption := ThisShellLinkRecord.Target;
  {$ELSE}
    Form1.Caption := 'This is a 64-bit program';
    Label1.Caption := JclFileUtils.PathGetLongName(ThisShellLinkRecord.Target);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Here are the visual results:
http://goo.gl/MttrZA
http://goo.gl/hvQqP6

**EDIT3**: Here is the encoded link file (`Xara Designer Pro X9.lnk`, encoded with `Soap.EncdDecd.EncodeBase64`):
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Comment: can you upload the .lnk file? Or post it here base64 encoded.

Comment: FWIW, Even GetPath of ShellLink with SLGP_RAWPATH returns the wrong path. +1

Comment: I've been trying to locate any documentation related to this issue, and haven't found any, other than a comment at the foot of the [IShellLink::GetPath documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which confirms this behavior exists outside Delphi/JCL (see "Known Bug" comment dated 02/27/2012).

Comment: Thanks for the base64 lnk file. I'll look at this later. Not terribly hopeful I'll be able to offer any hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this help: direct reading of target path from lnk file via parsing of internal structures:

```
type
  TdecShellLinkHeader = packed record
    HeaderSize: DWORD;
    LinkCLSID: TGUID;
    LinkFlags: DWORD;
    FileAttributes: DWORD;
    CreationTime: TFILETIME;
    AccessTime: TFILETIME;
    WriteTime: TFILETIME;
    FileSize: DWORD;
    IconIndex: Integer;
    ShowCommand: DWORD;
    HotKey: Word;
    Reserved1: Word;
    Reserved2: DWORD;
    Reserved3: DWORD;
  end;

const
  LnkFileCLSID: TGUID = '{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';

function DirectReadTargetNameFromLnkFile(const AFileName: UnicodeString): UnicodeString;
var
  Stream: TStream;
  Header: TdecShellLinkHeader;
  Size: Word;
  IDList: PItemIDList;
  Desktop: IShellFolder;
  ShellFolder: IShellFolder;
  ChildItem: PItemIDList;
  StrRet: TStrRet;
  AnsiResult: AnsiString;
  Result2: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := '';
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Header, SizeOf(Header));
    if not (Header.HeaderSize = SizeOf(Header)) or
      not IsEqualCLSID(Header.LinkCLSID, LnkFileCLSID) then
        raise Exception.Create('Invalid Lnk file');

    if Header.LinkFlags and SLDF_HAS_ID_LIST <> 0 then
      begin
        Stream.ReadBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
        IDList := CoTaskMemAlloc(Size);
        try
          Stream.ReadBuffer(IDList^, Size);
          OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop));
          try
            OleCheck(SHBindToParent(IDList, IShellFolder, Pointer(ShellFolder), ChildItem));
            try
              OleCheck(ShellFolder.GetDisplayNameOf(ChildItem, SHGDN_FORPARSING, StrRet));
              case StrRet.uType of
                STRRET_WSTR:
                  begin
                    Result := StrRet.pOleStr;
                    CoTaskMemFree(StrRet.pOleStr);
                  end;
                STRRET_OFFSET:
                  begin
                    Inc(PByte(ChildItem), StrRet.uOffset);
                    Result := UnicodeString(PAnsiChar(ChildItem));
                  end;
                STRRET_CSTR:
                  Result := UnicodeString(AnsiString(StrRet.cStr));
              else Result := '';
              end;
              Exit;
            finally
              ShellFolder := nil;
            end;
          finally
            Desktop := nil;
          end;
        finally
          CoTaskMemFree(IDList);
        end;
      end;

    if Header.LinkFlags and SLDF_HAS_LINK_INFO <> 0 then
      begin
        Stream.ReadBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
        Stream.Seek(Size - SizeOf(Size), soFromCurrent);
      end;

    if Header.LinkFlags and SLDF_HAS_NAME <> 0 then
      begin
        Stream.ReadBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
        if Header.LinkFlags and SLDF_UNICODE <> 0 then
          Stream.Seek(Size * SizeOf(WideChar), soFromCurrent)
        else
          Stream.Seek(Size * SizeOf(AnsiChar), soFromCurrent);
      end;

    if Header.LinkFlags and SLDF_HAS_RELPATH <> 0 then
      begin
        Stream.ReadBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
        if Header.LinkFlags and SLDF_UNICODE <> 0 then
          begin
            SetLength(Result, Size);
            if Size > 0 then
              Stream.ReadBuffer(PWideChar(Result)^, Size * SizeOf(WideChar));
          end
        else
          begin
            SetLength(AnsiResult, Size);
            if Size > 0 then
              Stream.ReadBuffer(PAnsiChar(AnsiResult)^, Size * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
            Result := AnsiResult;
          end;

        if Header.LinkFlags and SLDF_HAS_EXP_SZ <> 0 then
          begin
            Size := ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(PWideChar(Result), nil, 0);
            if Size > 1 then
              begin
                SetLength(Result2, Size - 1);
                ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(PWideChar(Result), PWideChar(Result2), Size);
                Result := Result2;
              end;
          end;

        Result2 := ExtractFileDir(AFileName);
        while Pos('..\', Result) = 1 do
          begin
            Result2 := ExtractFileDir(Result2);
            Delete(Result, 1, 3);
          end;
        Result := Result2 + '\' + Result;
      end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**USE ON YOUR OWN RISK!**

Comment: Note that `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` is also vulnerable to virtualization, you might need to parse that also.

Comment: I already examined lnk file specification. I cannot find any sample where target name contains environment variables.

Comment: Of course. Otherwise how would you write this answer. I posted the link because you didn't, it was addressed to OP.

Comment: This seems to work well. Has anybody encountered any errors with this code?

Comment: I use this as a replacement for `JclShell.ShellLinkResolve` to get the target of a Shortcut .LNK file. The reason is: If the target of a Shortcut .LNK file does not exist anymore then when using `JclShell.ShellLinkResolve` the system tries to find the target and blocks the whole system! Is it possible to avoid this?